# Anyone familiar with this "AceDB" file format?

Tags: file-format

I'm currently engrossed in penetration testing my Samsung SPH-M330. And to be fair, I have found a couple entry points (WHY ARE YOU PEOPLE USING STRCPY()!?)

Anyway, I'm now taking a look at "/brew/card1/DB/Ace.dat" as it defines the installed J2ME programs and I've figured out a way to modify it.

Problem is, I don't know what this "AceDB" format is. Interesting how the beginning of the file is: "AceDB Created By Insun Kang,"..."SangJung Woo". Not something you expect in a binary blob! Intriguingly, the phone is the one generating that text. Delete "Ace.dat" and restart the phone, all the listed games/apps disappear, but that string is still present in the "now empty" file.

Anyone familiar with this? Here's a link to the samples I've uploaded: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12QpbYtsb6BlMgAw2A3nHM_bGzfi6tJzZ

Comment: The only SangJung Woo on LinkedIn [is an employee of Samsung](https://www.linkedin.com/in/sangjungwoo/) and lists responsibilities including "Database Core development such as Catalog system and Heap manager" for the period from 2007–2010, during which the SPH-M330 came out. An Insun Kang was also [at Samsung until 2007](https://www.linkedin.com/in/insun-kang-1147396/). Odds on it's a proprietary Samsung file format.

Comment: Good digging thanks! Looks like I have my work cut out then.

Comment: Or maybe you can dump the firmware and look at where the string is generated

Comment: I would, but unfortunately that isn't really an option as both ram and nand dumping via the debug port is disabled on the phone.

Comment: It's probably the format described in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0164121209000491?via%3Dihub) which is unfortunately not available for free unless your university or such has access to it. You can buy it though. - Someone [here](https://blog.moneybag.de/c750-serie-pvr-aufnahmezeit-beim-samsung-manuell-andern/comment-page-1/#comment-1310) described in 2011 they were able to find code to access such a DB online and were able to compile it but they didn't link the source so even though it may exist in the Wayback Machine, I don't know where without URL...